# UI Dialog - pageX pageY position

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've constructed a data page with many rows of data (over 300 table rows). 
In each row I have an image the triggers a small ui dialog containing HTML (a context type menu). 
If I click any if the trigger images in the viewport there is no issue.
If I scroll down and click a trigger image the ui is always aligned to the bottom of my page, not the element I clicked.

```
function showMenu(){
$("#modalMenu").dialog("open");
return false;
}
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#modalMenu').dialog({autoOpen: false,modal: true,height: 200,width: 200});
$('.menu').click(function(e){$('#modalMenu').dialog('option', 'position', [e.pageX,e.pageY]);});
$('.menu').click(function(){showMenu();});
});



<div id="modalMenu">
  <a href="">Do Something</a>
  <a href="">Do Something Else</a>
</div>


<img class="menu" src="images/menu trigger.jpg" />

** This image is in the first cell of every row
```

Comment: Could you make a demo of this on [jsFiddle](http://jsFiddle.net/)? You mention table rows but the example code in the question shows no table rows. That aside, I suspect this is something that [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) will be able to help with...

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Needed to capture scrollTop, then deduct from e.pageY.
This accounts for position after scroll.

```
$('.menu').click(function(e){
  var y=$(window).scrollTop(); 
  $('#modalMenu').dialog('option', 'position', [e.pageX,(e.pageY-y)]);
  });
```